# Not able to differentiate between 91 and 19 using REGEX

Tags: regex

I'm using below REGEX for Indian number formatting like **91**9639458752

```
[91]{2}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}
```

but what's happening is it's accepting 19 as well i.e. **19**9639458752
which is absolutely wrong. Please suggest

Answer (score 3):

Note that `[91]{2}` means two digits which are either 1 or 9.  If you intend to match Indian phone numbers *starting* with country code `91`, then add boundary markers to your regex pattern:

```regex
^91[1-9][0-9]{9}$
```

Comment: Maybe `{1}` is not necessary? Or for some regex flavor has to do that?

Comment: Correct, it is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
91[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}
```

If that doesn't meet your need, please give more details on what you exactly want :)